# Retrieve Facebook Post Comments Using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to get Facebook comments using:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments
```

It results only 2 of 15 comments, and without `count` info.

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "[post_id]",
            "from": {
                "name": "[name]",
                "id": "[id]"
             },
             "message": "[message]",
             "created_time": "2011-01-23T02:36:23+0000"
        },
        {
             "id": "[id]",
             "from": {
             "name": "[name]",
                 "id": "[id]"
             },
            "message": "[message]",
            "created_time": "2011-01-23T05:16:56+0000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone know why only 2 comments?

Also, I want to retrieve comments (default number) or retrieve comments with my limit number, and get its comments count. Any idea? (Please use Graph API).

Comment: Hi Jeaffrey, could you please provide an example post with this behaviour? I checked several posts and the API always returns all comments. Make sure you provide proper `Post_ID`

Comment: @JeaffreyGilbert how cani get Post_ID  for getting comments for that pls. suggest me ,, i use same feature in my application

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to call it from a secure request `https` and provide an `access_token`:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_118464504835613/comments?access_token=XXX
```

**EDIT:**
Added the object from the [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) document. try clicking the `comments` connection and then remove the `access_token` and try and see the difference.

Comment: Does access_token need fb app? I don't want people have to authorize my app first, except they want to put a comment. Am I in right direction?

Comment: @Jeafrey Gilbert: as long as they are commenting on something YOU own, then don't have to authorize your app or deal with it. You just need to be authorize...so the `access_token` is yours

Comment: no, you wouldn't know if it is something YOU own if you don't login. I think he needs to create an app ID and ask the user to login and authorize first.

Comment: Sorry I misread... If what YOU own is public, yes you can see it even if you're not authorized. But wouldn't you still need to be authorized to make any comments?

Comment: @the_great_monkey: 1)please don't down-vote before reading and understanding the problem. 2)even if what you own is public, depending what are the commenter privacy settings you may not be able to retrieve their comments without being authenticated.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I did use your code and got the comments and like of the posts. But, here is one of my concern. Where will i get the access_token as i am doing this reading comments and like from the website end. SO, I found a solution that the appid|app_secret will work as access_token . But here they arenot working. I also cant save the app generated access_token at server end. Because it will expire after 60 days as per facebook documentaion. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ifaour I believe the `19292868552_118464504835613` represent the `object_id`. If that's the case, where can I get the object ID of my post?

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the `Like` count and the `comment` count then you need to use a combination of the `PostOwnerID` and `PostID` not just the `PostID`

So for your example it would be:

`https://graph.facebook.com/153125724720582_184234384932460/comments`

Again, as mentioned in some of the other answers you need to use the `https` method along with an `auth_token`

Comment: where can I get the `PostID` and `PostOwnerID` from?

Answer (score 4):

There is a word JUGAAR in Urdu that means, finding a way out, just to get the job done. So for like purpose I made this JUGAAR, I hope it helps.

```php
$contents = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/" . $_GET['id'] . "/likes");
if (substr_count($contents, 'name')>0) {
    echo substr_count($contents, 'name') . " people like this album";
}
```

By the way I am also new to this Fb stuff, I am looking for help to post comments. When I try to use graph.api./id/comments?access_token=sdfsfsdf&message="D" it still returns comments for the id instead of posting.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem with comments.  The issue was that I was using an access token for a test user.  Because test users don't have access to other FB users information, only the comments from pages were shown.

Answer (score 3):

As a sanity check, do you have "read_stream" permission? I can see the full comments with my access token that uses "read_stream". As mentioned by other people, you have to use https and access token as well...

Answer (score 1):

Try to authenticate via App Login (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) and then to call GraphAPI with access_token prarameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to avoid the whole count of comments issues:

1. Get the object's ([a post is considered an object in the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api)) ID-as I understand from your question, you already have it?
2. Create a [Comments Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments) with this ID, and get the code for it.
3. Embed the code in your site.

This will result in all the comments for this object.

To get the count of comments per object, you can execute an [fql query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/), something like this:

`SELECT comments FROM stream WHERE post_id = [yourpostid]`

This will return in the **comments** array under the **count** parameter the number of counts for this object.

Comment: how can i get post_id for getting comments ,pls. suggest me!

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya 

Use this snippet to test in developement


var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});

Answer (score 1):

SELECT comments FROM stream WHERE post_id = [yourpostid] shall not work in this case ..

the id which is returned after making a graph call successfully to post on a user's wall (using access_token of an application ) is of the form abcdef_qwerty ( underscore seperated id )
where as the post id which is mapped in the post_id of the comments table is of the form "lmnop" ..

to get the counts of like and comments on this post id of form "abcdef_qwerty" making a graph call withh app generated access token seems to be the only solution ..

something like:
https://graph.facebook.com/100002619172565_117323155031656?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: how can i get 100002619172565_117323155031656 like id for getting  all comments?

Comment: You get this in response of posting on user's wall using graph API

Answer (score 1):

> It results only 2 of 15 comments

Add a limit parameter to the URL:

```
 http://graph.facebook.com/[post_id]/comments?limit=1000&access_token=XXX
```

This should show all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**After Successfully Login call this method facebookComments()**

**parameters.putString("fields", "message"); .............//  Its Important**

```
 AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    public void facebookComments() {
        try {
            getFriends(accessToken, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.e("keshav", "one" + response);
                            CommonMethod.showAlert("res  --> " + response, MainActivity.this);
                        }
                    }
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CommonMethod.showAlert("Exception is -> " + e, MainActivity.this);
        }
    }

    public void getFriends(AccessToken token, GraphRequest.Callback callback)
    {
        // TODO Comments Working but id return only
        GraphRequest requestt = new GraphRequest(token, "744511125731315_751199848395776/comments",
                null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id");           // todo in use imp
        parameters.putString("fields", "name");           // todo in use imp
        parameters.putString("fields", "from");           // todo in use imp
        parameters.putString("fields", "message");           // todo in use imp
        requestt.setParameters(parameters);
        requestt.executeAsync();
    }
```