# Facebook Graph API get all comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I've put a Facebook social plugin comments box on my site, in which i specified a Facebook Fanpage, as the comments target.

Now what I want to do is get all comments that are present in the comments box on page my page. I'm using this:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=xxx

In place of xxx I placed my fanpage url (displayed comments just from one day even with limit set to 10000) and when this didn't work I tried my page url, which resulted in nothing being displayed.

Answer (score 14):

The correct syntax to read comments from the Facebook Graph API is as follows:

`GET /{object-id}/comments`

So your URL would look like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/comments

Here's a live example that looks at comments on Coca-Cola's cover photo:

http://graph.facebook.com/10152297032458306/comments

You can read more about reading comments via the Graph API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graphapi/guides/comments/#reading).

Comment: how can i generate object id when i have url as my only resource..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806802/get-list-of-all-comments-using-url/19807222?noredirect=1#comment29449187_19807222

Comment: @cormac driver but live example return a error ..why?

Comment: After the privacy issue, Facebook updated the comment API. You can only do the followings:
1) Query the comments on your own post by user token
2) Query the comment by you on that post

which is quite useless.

Answer (score 5):

check [this stackOverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791951/retrieve-facebook-post-comments-using-graph-api)

You need to call it from a secure request https and provide an `access_token` (19292868552_118464504835613 is Facebook post) :

( (19292868552) is the page or group id  and (118464504835613) is the post id)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_118464504835613/comments?access_token=XXX
```

EDIT:
Added the object from the post document. Try clicking the `comments` connection and then remove the `access_token` and try and see the difference.

Comment: 19292868552_118464504835613 is Facebook post is

Comment: Where can I find the object ID / post ID?

Comment: You can find the post-id (using the page id: 19292868552) in the list of posts:
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552/posts?access_token=XXX