# Facebook Graph API get page's comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

Using Facebook Graph API, I want to get that all comments that presents in a page and filter them based on datetime.
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439804/facebook-graph-api-get-all-comments) thread, but it doesn't help as expected.

I can get all post and limit using date for specific page e.g.:

```
graph.facebook.com/110432309005026/tagged?since=<unix timestamp>
```

Now I want to do the same to search all comments.
This is how I do so far:

```
graph.facebook.com/110432309005026/tagged?fields=comments{id,from,message,created_time}
```

But how to filter the date of comment (not the date of post) ?
For example, I want to get all comment since `'2015-04-25 00:00:00'` for all posts on my page.

Need your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are looking for exactly however, what you could do is also look into just filtering the posts returned by the /tagged endpoint using the since parameter.

Since you are only looking for comments from a certain date when you fetch the posts from a certain date then the comments can ONLY be from that date. Your request will look like this instead:

```
graph.facebook.com/110432309005026/tagged?fields=comments{id,from,message,created_time}&since=2015-04-25
```

Comment: the consequence is I'm unable to grab a new comment from older post's date beyond the date that is specified by 'since' parameter. Understand that it seems a limitation of API,  I think I should notify my users about this. Thanks @The1Fitz