# Embed a Facebook Page Post including Comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking at how to embed a Facebook Page Post using [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts#add-code-manually). I like the way this looks, but it doesn't allow for the comments to also be shown at the same time. My goal is to create a dashboard of page post and display it on a TV in the hallway. None of the posts have more than 10 comments so it wouldn't get out of hand. Is there a way to accomplis this using the api I linked, or do I need to spin up my own iframe to include the comments?

Comment: The documentation states: "The embedded post will show any media attached to it, as well as the number of likes, shares, and comments that the post has." So it should have comments.

Comment: It only shows the number of comments that it has, not the actual comments.

Comment: You could use the Facebook Graph API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439804/facebook-graph-api-get-all-comments

Comment: Here is a link directly to the API details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments/

Comment: @Crosbie Thanks, that does work. I'll have rig something up with the page post and the comments together. It would be nice to have an all in one solution...

Comment: Ya. Looks like you have some work ahead of you. Good luck!

Comment: @Crosbie if you want to turn your suggestion to use the comments api directly into an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the best way to list the comments of a Facebook page post is to use the Facebook Graph API. Here is a direct link to the comments API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/comments