# I am going to do a sentiment analysis research on facebook comments.any idea how can I coolect facebook comments for my research?

Tags: reproducible-research

I am doing sentimental analysis research for my final year research for facebook comments. But I don't know how can I collect facebook comment's data.

Comment: Read up on Cambridge Analytica, both to learn how they gained access to Facebook profiles, and so you're aware of the risks of ToS violations https://theintercept.com/2017/03/30/facebook-failed-to-protect-30-million-users-from-having-their-data-harvested-by-trump-campaign-affiliate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook Graph API get all comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439804/facebook-graph-api-get-all-comments)

This might be a useful starting point, as someone with a similar project goal.

I'd probably go with a programming language you're comfortable with, searh for a Facebook API software wrapper (Python) or package (R Studio), and read up on what the functions do.

Comment: After the privacy issue, Facebook has updated the comment API